# Does anybody know what this ui element is called?

Tags: android, view, toggle

Src - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkz0q.jpg

It acts like a toggle button but it the circle switches position. Is this a custom view or a view from the actual android library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to this in Android is a Switch:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

The example you posted is either a Switch with a custom style or a custom UI element.